# mediaplayer does not work android

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

This is the function that suppose to play some sound when a notification is set

```
private void playRingtone() {
    AudioManager am = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    if (am.getRingerMode() == AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL) {
        try {
            MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.notification_ringtone);
            mp.start();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "MediaPlayer problem");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

using the debugger everything goes smoothly but no sound is played. WHY???

Comment: Check that `mp` isn't `null` after your call to `create(...)` before calling `mp.start()`.

Comment: Then in that case it seems either `R.raw.notification_ringtone` doesn't contain any valid audio or you have the volume turned down on your test device.

Answer (score 0):

```
    MediaPlayer  mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

    try {
mediaPlayer.setDataSource("android.resource://YOURPACKAGE_NAME/raw/"+file anme);    
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
            mediaPlayer.start();
    }catch(Exceptions e){
    }
```

Comment: How is this of any real difference to what the OP is already doing? The `create(...)` methods of `MediaPlayer` are convenience methods which implicitly create an instance, set the data source and prepare the `MediaPlayer` instance.